# how to compute average ROC for cross validated for multiclass

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, roc

I'm recently struggling with using sklearn for my project.
I wanted to build a classifier and classify my data into six groups. the total sample size was 88 then I split the data into train(66) and test(22)
I did exactly as sklearn documentation showed, here is my code

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis as QDA

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(QDA())
QDA_score = clf.fit(train,label).decision_function(test)
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(3):
     fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(label_test[:, i], QDA_score[:, i])
     roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
from itertools import cycle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
lw = 2

colors = cycle(['aqua', 'darkorange', 'cornflowerblue'])
for i, color,n in zip(range(3), colors,['_000','_15_30_45','60']):
plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], color=color, lw=lw,
         label='ROC curve of {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'
         ''.format(n , roc_auc[i]))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--', lw=lw)
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('ROC for multi-classes')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

the link is my result.
however every time I run the code the result changes. I'm wondering if there is anyway that I can combine this with Cross validation and compute average and stable ROC for each class

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! I'm reviewing first posts. I suggest adding a link to the documentation you're working from. Also the link with results you're referring to seems to be missed. It would also help if you could better isolate the code portion that is changing behavior and explain why that is unexpected. Otherwise, this is a pretty good first post. Good luck!

Comment: @Meng see my answer and let me know

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `cross_val_predict` to first get the cross-validated probabilities and then plot the ROC curve for each class.**

*Example using Iris data*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis as QDA

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Binarize the output
y_bin = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = y_bin.shape[1]

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(QDA())
y_score = cross_val_predict(clf, X, y, cv=10 ,method='predict_proba')

fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_bin[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
colors = cycle(['blue', 'red', 'green'])
for i, color in zip(range(n_classes), colors):
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], color=color, lw=lw,
             label='ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'
             ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--', lw=lw)
plt.xlim([-0.05, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic for multi-class data')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

**To get the ROC for each Fold do this:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold


iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X, y = X[y != 2], y[y != 2]
n_samples, n_features = X.shape

# Add noisy features
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]

# Classification and ROC analysis

# Run classifier with cross-validation and plot ROC curves
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6)
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
                     random_state=random_state)

tprs = []
aucs = []
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

i = 0
for train, test in cv.split(X, y):
    probas_ = classifier.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
    # Compute ROC curve and area the curve
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y[test], probas_[:, 1])
    tprs.append(interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr))
    tprs[-1][0] = 0.0
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    aucs.append(roc_auc)
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, lw=1, alpha=0.3,
             label='ROC fold %d (AUC = %0.2f)' % (i, roc_auc))

    i += 1
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', lw=2, color='r',
         label='Luck', alpha=.8)

mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)
mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
std_auc = np.std(aucs)
plt.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, color='b',
         label=r'Mean ROC (AUC = %0.2f $\pm$ %0.2f)' % (mean_auc, std_auc),
         lw=2, alpha=.8)

std_tpr = np.std(tprs, axis=0)
tprs_upper = np.minimum(mean_tpr + std_tpr, 1)
tprs_lower = np.maximum(mean_tpr - std_tpr, 0)
plt.fill_between(mean_fpr, tprs_lower, tprs_upper, color='grey', alpha=.2,
                 label=r'$\pm$ 1 std. dev.')

plt.xlim([-0.05, 1.05])
plt.ylim([-0.05, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic example')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, is the second example for multiclass as well? If yes, I assume `y[test]` is a categoric variable with 3 values? My `y` is also like that, and for some reason whenever I run this, an error appears in the `roc_curve(y[test], probas_[:, 1])` saying multiclass form is not supported... any solution for that? :)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without more details of the data and the comlexity of the problem you are trying to solve, but irregular learning performance like yours could indicate that your dataset is too small for the irregularity and complexity of the data, so that every time you sample you get a train dataset which is different.

A common test vs train stabling technique you could also look into is [k-fold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) cross validation.

UPDATE:
K-fold cross validation is basically slicing the data into k parts and then do the learning process k times and average their results, where each time a different part of the data is the test dataset and the rest k-1 parts are the train dataset.

Comment: seems there are plenty of method for cross validation in sklearn. May I ask what is the difference between k-fold function and cross_val_score?

Comment: well I know the concept but I'm just confused about the difference between the two functions..

Comment: k-fold is essentially averaging k runs of cross_val_score.